# How can I build an intuitive sense of the relative cost of WebAssembly instructions?

Tags: performance, compiler-optimization, webassembly

I'm building a [simple compiler](https://github.com/captbaritone/eel-wasm) which emits WebAssembly. As I craft the Wasm that the compiler will emit, there are often multiple ways to implement a given behavior and I'm left unsure which one would be more performant.

For example, there are some cases where I could chain some math instructions to avoid storing/retrieving a value into/out of a variable. When is that tradeoff worth making? Is that even a thing I should be considering?

Obviously the only real answer to that question is "build both and then measure the performance on multiple Wasm interpreters", but that feels infeasible for the number of questions I have. I'm guessing there are some types of instructions which are an order of magnitude more expensive than others, and knowing that would help me make better intuitive decisions.

Are there any rules of thumb for how to think about this? Has anyone written about this? Are there tools which will show me what a given browser/interpreter would compile a snippet of Wasm to?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something similar to JsPerf but for WASM.

The performance is going to depend on the browser and version you're using and I'm afraid there isn't a good answer here. If you take a look at js performance over time, compilers do help a bit but it is the vendors who can do something meaningful.

Over time we can expect the gap between wasm and native apps to short quite a bit and I suspect the main bottleneck for wasm is the bridge between js and wasm.

There is a paper that may interest you: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/atc19-jangda.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize you Wasm code to reduce the **size of the output**. Indeed, a smaller output file can be downloaded faster. This is important if your Wasm code is stored on a web server and executed in client browsers.

Beside this, the Wasm compiler in the browser could optimize the code too. But even in such case, it is not totally pointless to do the optimizations ahead of time in your compiler because the browser putting **more burden to the browser** will likely often cause it to compile the code to a native binary more slowly. This results in **slightly bigger loading times or slightly less responsive web applications**.